# Build queries from Jekyll csv data file

Tags: csv, for-loop, jekyll, data-files

So I have a csv file with rows of data called "opportunities.csv"

This file is in the _data folder of my Jekyll site

```
client,opp,person,status
Oracle,"New thing five","Mary Smith",lead
Oracle,"Data plan","Sue Curry",lead
Oracle,"Migration 2019","Sue Curry",lead
IBM, "Platform assessment","Jane Campton",lost
```

I'd like to display the number of leads per person:

```
Mary Smith    1 lead
Sue Curry     2 lead
Jane Campion  0 lead
```

So, for each "person" in "site.opportunities" count the number of rows for each instance of "person" where "status" = "lead"

I now this involves incrementing counters inside nested for loops but I just can't seem to get it working.

I could change the data file format to json or yml but in my current use case I have other non-technical team members editing a csv file in excel so that's a given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `group_by` and `where` filters :

```
{% assign groups = site.data.opportunities | group_by: "person" %}
<ul>
{% for g in groups %}
{% assign leads = g.items | where: "status", "lead" %}
<li>name : {{ g.name }} {{ leads.size }} leads</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow David, this is fantastic. I built your code and works perfectly. I wonder how many amazing filters like "group_by" like buried in Shopify documentation:-) Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: Here, `group_by` and `where` are Jekyll's specific filters. See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/